# Kafka Consumer not fetching last committed value

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

`Producer` sending messages continuously... I checked the `offset` value before stopping the `consumer`, it was 8023. after 10mins I started `consumer` then the first offset value is 8020. After some time again I stopped `consumer` at that time offset value is 9239 after an hour I started `consumer` then the first message offset value is 9299 I am setting `auto.offset.reset` as `latest` I am also logging the `partition` value , it is `0` only. If I stop `consumer` after 8092 when I restart it after 30mins it has to fetch from 8093

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consumer only takes `auto.offset.reset` into account if there are no committed offsets for the group it's using. Otherwise, it restarts from the last committed offset.

By default, the consumer automatically commits offsets every 5 seconds, so depending on the message rate, the last committed offset is always a few records being the latest received offset.

In order to reduce this gap, you have a few options:

- Disable `auto.commit.offset`, and use manual commit, so you control when offsets are committed.
- Reduce the `auto.commit.interval.ms` interval, so offsets are committed more often.

Note that committing more often comes with a slight performance cost.

---

One last thing about `auto.offset.reset`:

When set to `latest`, it instructs the consumer to restart from the end of the log. For example, if you stop your consumer at offset 5000. If before restarting it, you've produced messages till offset 6000, with `latest` the consumer will restart consuming from 6000 and will completely skip messages from 5000 to 6000.